# An application of the pigeonhole principle on a $7\times 7$ board

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Before moving on to my main question, I would like to write the basic question that I know the solution method well.

**Basic Question:** Prove that no matter how $50$ points are chosen from inside or over a square with a side length of $7$ units, there are two points with a distance is $\leq \sqrt{2}$ between them.

**Solution:** Let's split the board in $7\times 7$ type. So we have $49$ unit squares. According to the pigeonhole principle, $ \left\lfloor\dfrac{50}{49}\right\rfloor + 1 = 2$ points are in or on the same square. The distance between them is $\leq \sqrt{2}$.

At this stage, the following question came to my mind:

**Main Question:** No matter how $n$ points are taken from inside (or over) a square with side lengths of $7$ units, there can always be a pair of points whose distance is $\leq \sqrt{2}$ unit. What is the smallest value of $n$ that makes this condition possible?

At first I thought the answer would simply be $50$. I tried to place the points as close to each other as the distance between them was slightly greater than $\sqrt{2}$. I got $32$ points. So I feel that $n = 32+1=33$ is the minimum desired value. I have no rigorous proof.

Thank you for your advice and assistance.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted and then deleted an answer.  I underestimated how difficult the problem is.  For example, for the basic question, once you divide the region into $(49)$ squares, each of dimension $1 \times 1$.  it is unclear to me that there is a way of placing $(49)$ distinct points in that square such that the distance between any two points is $~> \sqrt{2}.$  So, I deleted my answer.

Comment: In your main question, do you really mean "two pairs of points", or just one pair of points?

Comment: @RaviFernando The way that I interpret the main question, (which may be erroneous) is that the main question is ambiguous.  It could be that the OP (i.e. original poster) intends that if you have (for example) $3$ distinct points $P_1, P_2, P_3$, such that $P_2$ is within $\sqrt{2}$ of the other two points, that this qualifies as *two pairs of points*.  The alternative interpretation that I thought of is that you must have $(4)$ distinct points $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ such that $P_1,P_2$ are close to each other and $P_3,P_4$ are close to each other.

Comment: @RaviFernando , "a pair of points". Thank you for your notice. I made a translation error. I've just corrected.

Comment: hi, do you mean $\leq \sqrt{2}$ in the basic question?

Comment: @l4teLearner , yes. I used "$\leq \sqrt{2}$" to mean "less or equal $\sqrt{2}$ "

Comment: nitpick: you wrote "with a distance is $\sqrt{2}$"

Comment: @l4teLearner thank you for your notice, Now I could see it (and I fixed it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of arranging points in a square with no two points near each other is equivalent to the well-studied problem of [packing circles in a square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square).  Specifically, if you choose $n$ points in a $7 \times 7$ square with no two points within $\sqrt 2$ units of each other, then the circles of radius $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ centered on the given points do not intersect and are all contained in a square of side length $7 + \sqrt 2$.  The converse holds as well.

As a result, after rescaling distances, you are asking how many unit circles can be packed in a square of side length $(7 + \sqrt 2) \cdot \sqrt 2 = 7 \sqrt 2 + 2 \approx 11.8995$.  According to [here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq.html), the answer to this is 35:  the tightest possible packing of $36$ unit circles is in a square of side length $12$ (in a square grid), while $35$ unit circles can be packed in a square of side length at most $s \approx 11.8637$ (picture [here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d3.html), not known to be optimal).  This corresponds to a packing of $35$ points in a square of side length $\frac{s-2}{\sqrt 2} \approx 6.9747$ with all distances at least $\sqrt 2$ (or a slightly larger square with all distances greater than $\sqrt 2$).  Meanwhile, for $36$ points you would need a square of side length at least $\frac{12 - 2}{\sqrt 2} \approx 7.071$.

Comment: Very nice explantion!